# Snake game with c++ OOB

Tags: c++, oop, access-violation

I wrote a snake game in c++ in console and i have some issues that I can't understand. Could anyone help me? According to code below:

```cpp
class Snake : public Fruit{
    private:
        int head;
        short dir_x;    //-1 (left or down) / +1 (right or up)
        short dir_y;

        friend class Game;

        int base_length = 3;    // base length of snake on start of the game
        const int length = Board::global_x * Board::global_y;   // max length
        int prev_tailPos[2];    // previous tail position (end of snake)
        int tail;               // tail is sum of base_length and score             
        int time = 100;         //  delay for snake

        struct Body{
            int body_pos[2]; // position of every element of snakes body
            Body* higherEl;  // point element nearer head element
        };
        Body* body = new Body[length];  // array for body of snake
};
```

With that order everything is fine, but if I put definition of struct Body, and body on top of that class, just like that:

```cpp
class Snake : public Fruit{
    private:
        struct Body{
            int body_pos[2]; // position of every element of snakes body
            Body* higherEl;  // point element nearer head element
        };
        Body* body = new Body[length];  // array for body of snake

        int head;
        short dir_x;    //-1 (left or down) / +1 (right or up)
        short dir_y;

        friend class Game;

        int base_length = 3;    // base length of snake on start of the game
        const int length = Board::global_x*Board::global_y; // max length
        int prev_tailPos[2];    // previous tail position (end of snake)
        int tail;               // tail is sum of base_length and score             
        int time = 100;         //  delay for snake
};
```

After I stop the game this error shows up:

```
> Unhandled Exception at 0x76C40860 (sechost.dll) in Snake.exe: 
> 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004`
```

Can someone help me why that is a problem?

Comment: Um... Why is your snake a fruit? I'm not sure OOP would be of any help with a snake game, much less in this way...

Comment: @Quentin Would you be ok with it if the snake was a leek? ;)

Comment: @MaxLanghof I mean, it would *kind of* make sense with a sufficiently... flexible implementation of `class Leek`...

Comment: Yeah, i know that snake is not fruit. I know that it is not the best idea. Just for now i wanted to train a little with classes and make something. Snake is fruit jus because i wanted to have easy access to coordination of randomly generate fruit that snake has to eat. So i've come up with idea of inherit that class (to be more accurate snake is a friend of fruit for access to private data. Propably it should be achievable just from methods but .. yeah. Is that all make sense or not? Just to make sure :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that in your second example, the variable `length` is undefined at the time of evaluating
`Body* body = new Body[length];`.

This is most likely your problem.

To explain this a little further, you need to understand that:
**The order of the declaration of variables inside a class/struct is important**.

To illustrate:

```
class Data{
    int a = 10;
    int b = a;
};
```

In this example, both `a` and `b` will be equal to 10.
However, in a case like this:

```cpp
class Data{
    int b = a;
    int a = 10;
};
```

`a` will be 10 and `b` will have a trash value.
This is because when evaluating `int b = a;`. `a` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, i don;t know why i thought that it is okay. Is something like that fine though?
        class Data{
            int a;
            int b = a;
            a = 10;
         };

Comment: `int a;` and `int b = 10` and such work inside a class definition because it's initialization, and even that it is recommended to use member initialization lists over simple init statements. In your example, `a = 10;` is not initialization, but assignment. For that reason, such code wouldn't even compile.